# Подозрительное приложение заблокировано

Tags: android, android-sdk

Был фрилансер  программист, который сделал задачку для корпоративных пользователей.

Сейчас появилась задача дополнить проект, корректировки в код я внес, все отрабатывает,  но когда я создаю арк и устанавливаю на телефон, он выводит предупреждение + не может найти пред. версию приложения. Как говорит фрилансер , он не использовал подпись для приложения. Но в проекте , если зайти в меню подписи арк, там был ссылка на jks, если я указываю этот jks , то все равно все без изменений.

Добавлено - через android stud создаю подпись, но если через проверку прогоняю арк то пишет что подписи нет =(
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4\bin>keytool -printcert -jarfile C:\Driver\app\debug\app-debug.apk
Not a signed jar file

Вопрос - что сделать что бы предупреждение не выскакивало? (ранее на сборках его не было)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: Что за "предупреждение"? Что вы понимаете под "не может найти пред. версию"? Ставит новую рядом?

Comment: при запуске предлагает обновить приложение, но далее сначала выскакивает ошибка как на скрине (Подозрительное приложение заблокировано), и после этого Приложение не установлено, так как оно конфликтует с другим пакетом

Answer (score 0):

Ваше приложение не опубликовано в Google Play Store. Конфликтует с другим пакетом - удалите приложений, после установите новую версию.